# Java 6 equivalent of Integer.compare

Tags: java

In Java 7 I can use [`Integer.compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), but when I try to use it in Java 6 it gives me the error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method compare(int,int)
location: class java.lang.Integer
```

How do I create a similar function in Java 6?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is specified in the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29) :

> Compares two int values numerically. The value returned is identical
>   to what would be returned by:
>       `Integer.valueOf(x).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(y))`

So you can use :

```
Integer.valueOf(x).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(y))
```

---

> How do create a similar function in Java 6?

The source is open and you can find the implementation [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.compare%28int%2Cint%29).

```
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
      return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the implementation present in the **Java 7 implementation**

```
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

For your java 6 project, you wrap this in a utility class, and remove that class once you migrate to Java7

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Integer.valueOf(a).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

`public static int compare(int x, int y){
  return (x<y)?-1:((x==y)?0:1);
}`

1. use 'static' only if it is part of the utility class of which you don't intend to create an instance of
2. Notice the brackets are important to state action clearly
3. Values returned by the function: 
   -1 returned if xy
4. Java 7 onwards you don't need to implement this in the utility class, you can use Integer.compare(x,y) instead